# <c:forEach> tag can not evaluating arraylist elements properly

Tags: jsp, servlets

I can not get the elements in the arraylist, but I can output the student object as a whole string. Any ideas?

My Servlet page:

```
ArrayList<Student> students = Dao.getStudentList();
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("students", students);
```

I have a Dao class to connect to mySql database, and I also have static Arraylist defined globally in the class to store the student objects.

My JSP page:

```
<%
    ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
    if (request.getSession().getAttribute("students") != null) {
        list = (ArrayList ) request.getSession().getAttribute("students");
        }
    else {
        System.out.println("List is empty, Please insert new data");
    }

%>


    <table border="1" style="width: 800px">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Date of joined</th>
                    <th>Primary Address</th>
                    <th>Secondary Address</th>
                </tr>
            <c:set var="list"  scope="session">
                    <%= list %>
            </c:set> 
            <c:forEach items="${list}" var="lists">
                 <tr>   
                    <td>${lists.id}</td>
                    <td>${lists.name}</td>
                    <td>${lists.age}</td>
                    <td>${lists.doj}</td>
                    <td>${lists.address1}</td>
                    <td>${lists.address2}</td>      
                 </tr>
            </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

If I do

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="lists">
             <tr>   
                        <td>${lists}</td>
             </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

It output the object as a string. But it was not I am trying to do. I would like to output all the student object with corresponding elements as a table format.

Comment: STop using scriptlets and mixing scriptlets and the JSP EL. Put the Java code in the servlet, not in the JSP. Your <c:set> tag makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be interested in [Display Tags](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2//)for a change? They do all you need and much more.
Lets say we consider your data for our tags:

```
<display:table id="data" name="sessionScope.students">
    <display:column property="id" title="ID" sortable="true"/>
    <display:column property="name" title="Name" sortable="true"/>
    <display:column property="age" title="Age" sortable="true"/>
    <display:column property="doj" title="Date of joined" sortable="true"/>
</display:table>
```

These tags will provide you with a table which can have sortable columns, pagination and custom styling among other features.

Answer (score 0):

Instead may be you can try something like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.students}" var="student">
   <tr>   
    <td>${student.id}</td>
    <td>${student.name}</td>
    <td>${student.age}</td>
    <td>${student.doj}</td>
    <td>${student.address1}</td>
    <td>${student.address2}</td>      
   </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

and make sure your getter methods name matches your variable names (e.g. variable "id" should have getId() method).

Comment: Is sessionScope is a key word in jsp?? I tried the code you provided. It still not printout anything nor any errors. Please help.

Comment: Yes it is. Can you try putting ${sessionScope.students} somewhere in your html and see what it prints.

Comment: This method is still not working for me. I have switched to a method I know pretty well. I added java code inside jsp and used for loop print out data on the html page. Thanks!